# '\\' not in scope error after importing Data.List (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

my function prints different permutations given some numbers however i cannot load my file in ghci even AFTER i import Data.List. it tells me '\' is not in scope. please help

```
perms [] = [[]]
perms xs = [x:ps | x <- xs, ps <- perms(xs\\[x]) ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the import statement:

```
import Data.List ((\\))

perms :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
perms [] = [[]]
perms xs = [x:ps | x <- xs, ps <- perms(xs \\ [x]) ]
```

Comment: if i put that statement in the file it gives me an error on "import". should this be typed in ghci before i load the file?

Comment: when i write import Data.List ((\\)) in ghci i still get the same error :(

Comment: @Chalupa Are you sure you are not doing indendation error. It works fine in ideone: http://ideone.com/e5Gw0w

Comment: yea i have the same thing as you and i get this: Hask3.hs:92:1: parse error on input ‘import’
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: @Chalupa Looks like you're trying to put the import in the middle of your file.  All imports have to come between the module declaration (e.g. `module Main where`) and the first declaration in your file, be it a function, value, data type, typeclass, or whatever.